# Equivalent of the term "apocryphal", but for quotes?

Tags: terminology

A story is ***apocryphal*** if it's:

> of doubtful authenticity, although widely circulated as being true.

Despite not strictly being *true*, *apocryphal* stories can still be used to communicate a point or idea (often succinctly or entertainingly). Use of the adjective '*apocryphal*' allows full transparency about the possible inauthentic nature of the story.

#### Question

Is there any equivalent word to describe the quality of a quote possibly not having come from its supposed source/author?

#### An example

Some sources [claim](https://www.inc.com/geoffrey-james/a-messy-desk-is-a-sign-of-genius-according-to-scie.html) Albert Einstein said:

> If a cluttered desk is a sign of a cluttered mind, of what, then, is an empty desk a sign?

But other sources state that there's [no actual citation of Einstein ever saying that](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/09/02/clutter/).

Is there a word that achieves for quotes of uncertain sources what the term '*apocryphal*' achieves for stories of doubtful authenticity?

Comment: I suspect the term you are looking for is the one you already have: *apocryphal.*

Comment: Can you write a fill-in-the-blank sentence for how you want to use it?

Comment: 'apocryphally attributed to'

Answer (score 2):

**attributed** (adj.)

> Given as an attribute or appropriate possession; ascribed as proper
> to.
>
> 1854   *(title)*    Edward III: a Play attributed to Shakespeare. (OED)

**attribute** (v.)

> Ascribe a work or remark to (a particular author, artist, or speaker)
>
> *The building was attributed to Inigo Jones* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/attribute)

**misattribute** (v.)

> Wrongly attribute.
>
> *The professor misattributed Robert Burn's famous line to Shakespeare.* [Lexico](http://Wrongly%20attribute.%20%20%E2%80%98the%20professor%20misattributed%20Robert%20Burn%27s%20famous%20line%20to%20Shakespeare%E2%80%99)

---

> It is well-established that many of the most famous quotes are not
> accurate...In 2012, Quentin Schultze and Randall Bytwerk demonstrated
> that a quote **attributed** to Joseph Goebbels, beginning "If you tell
> a lie big enough and keep repeating it, people will eventually come to
> believe it', then found on over half a million pages of the internet,
> was never said by him. *They used the term '**referential credibility'**
> for when a quotation is believed by the community using it to have
> been correctly attributed to a person important to that community.*
> [Helen King; *Hippocrates Now*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hippocrates_Now/Ys6uDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22a%20quote%20attributed%20to%22&pg=PT90&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> They run a website for young people about books they like to read.
> This site, *Inside a Dog* (named from a quote **attributed** to
> Groucho Marx, 'Outside of a dog, a book is a man's best friend. Inside
> a dog, it's too dark to read') is 'all about books, by young people for young people'... [Andrew Goodwyn et. al; *The Future
> of English Teaching Worldwide*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Future_of_English_Teaching_Worldwide/H_h1DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22a%20quote%20attributed%20to%20Groucho%20marx%22&pg=PA223&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

> He was fond of the phrase “The coldest winter I ever spent was August
> in San Francisco”—an adaptation of a quote **misattributed** to Mark
> Twain —and used it to temper the glow of his happiness when sending
> notes to his colleagues out east. [Susannah Cahalan; *The Great
> Pretender*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Great_Pretender/qYyLDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22a%20quote%20misattributed%20to%22&pg=PT117&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

Answer (score 1):

*Apocryphal* works just fine for quotes. From the *OED* (see *statement*):

> **apocryphal**, *adj.* and *n.*
>
> **A.** *adj.* Of doubtful authenticity; spurious, fictitious, false; fabulous, mythical.
> **a.** *originally* of a writing, statement, or story.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Why, here are a few apocryphal quotes now!

> *Let them eat cake!* — Marie Antoinette
>
> *That’s one small step for man, one giant leap for mankind.* — Neil Armstrong
>
> *The end justifies the means* — Machiavelli
>
> *Be the change that you wish to see in the world* — Gandhi
>
> *Et tu, Brute?* — Julius Caesar
>
> *If the bees disappeared off the surface of the globe then man would only have four years of life left* — Albert Einstein
>
> <sub>Source: Unveiling History’s [Apocryphal quotes, or when we render
> to Caesar things that aren’t his at all](https://historicallysuitable.wordpress.com/2016/01/23/apocryphal-quotes-or-when-we-render-to-caesar-the-things-that-arent-his-at-all/)</sub>

Seen about:

> By the time Russert was working for then-Gov. Mario Cuomo in 1984, the
> New Yorker carried a possibly apocryphal quote from presidential
> candidate Gary Hart — “Get me a Russert!” — that fueled the
> operative’s legend.
>  <sub>Source: [*Washington Post* via *East Bay Times* — Media reeling
> from Russert’s
> death](https://www.eastbaytimes.com/2008/06/13/media-reeling-from-russerts-death/)</sub>

> One especially famous, if possibly apocryphal, quote that has been
> attributed to everyone from Frank Zappa to Elvis Costello to
> Thelonious Monk, pertains to the art of music criticism. It runs:
> “Writing about music is like —
>
> > dancing about architecture”
>
> <sub>Quiz source: [*The Guardian* — From Marilyn to Shakespeare: how
> well do you know history’s most bungled
> quotes?](https://www.theguardian.com/australia-news/2021/dec/04/from-marilyn-to-shakespeare-how-well-do-you-know-historys-most-bungled-quotes)</sub>

> A possibly apocryphal quote attributed to Mario Vargas Llosa puts it
> well: “Life is a shitstorm, in which Art is our only umbrella.”
> <sub>Source: [*Literary Hub* — Literature for This Long, Dark Night of
> America’s Soul](https://lithub.com/literature-for-this-long-dark-night-of-americas-soul/)</sub>

Comment: This is quite an incredible answer. The [*Apocryphal quotes ..*](https://historicallysuitable.wordpress.com/2016/01/23/apocryphal-quotes-or-when-we-render-to-caesar-the-things-that-arent-his-at-all/) reference you provided was a great read. Thank you!